# Davinci resolve stops generating subtitles in specific part of timeline

Tags: audio, davinci-resolve, subtitles

I'm having an issue generating automatic subtitles over a specific portion of my video. it worked just fine scanning the middle to end but it only gets off 2 subtitles in the beginning then stops for a few minutes

[image]

I only need titles for one layer so all the others are muted as to not interfere with generation. Generating without anything aside from the audio track itself did nothing. Anyone know what causes this?